# AJAX $.post not showing response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Geeks, I am stucked at very annoying stage in my AJAX code, actually am doing a simple POST request to my web-service hosted locally, using AJAX jquery post method.here is simple code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/send",
        {
          name: "swap",
          city: "amt"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The web service code is correct, when I CURL to my webservice it returns correct response, it means it's working fine. The above code was working fine a month ago, but when i try running it now, it's not working either, i checked some similar issues on stack overflow, but they were keep suggesting that, don't use cross-domain request using above code, but am running this code from my local PC. I also checked the response in wire-shark and I can clearly see that the the correct response is returned by webservice, I don't know why, this callback function is not executed by the Ajax code to show the response. As you can see in the code am not using any format like JSON or XML it's plain text but still the problem.

If any one cloud help me resolving this issue, It would be really great help to me.

Thank You.

Comment: use `jsonp` if the call is cross domain with `$.ajax()`

Comment: You seems a local request so AJAX should be ok. I'm wondering, are you sure that `send` does not have an extension? Like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/send.php` ? Is there a .htaccess on the local server handling it?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/send` this is the webservice with a port 5000, what about your app domain is it also on the same port number?

Comment: Pls, try doing a `console.log(data)` instead of the alert, and tellus the result

Comment: @swap Sreenshot from webconsole from network tab will be helpfull

Comment: The web-service is written in python. app domain is also at the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is your request failing?

What happens when you tail a `.fail` callback on the `post`?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("/send",
    {
      name: "swap",
      city: "amt"
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })
    .fail(function() { alert('Request failed!'); });
});
```

### If so, check if you have a CORS/mixed content problem

With the code you've linked above, the page which includes that JavaScript code must be being served from your local webserver at `127.0.0.1:5000`, or the webserver at `127.0.0.1:5000` must be sending back a [CORS header](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) within the response to the `/send` request.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header tells the browser which domains are trusted for serving pages that send cross origin requests.

Either way, all AJAX requests ***must*** be made from pages being served from a webserver. Modern browsers won't allow any XMLHttpRequests (AJAX requests) to execute if opening a file in a browser from the local file system.

Also, the webserver serving the page that contains the code in your question must be serving the page via HTTP and not HTTPs, otherwise the browser will block the request as [mixing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent).

Please check your browser's console to see if you're receiving any errors. (Press **CTRL+K** in FireFox or **CTRL+J** in Chromium)

Here's what the *mixed content* and *CORS* errors look like in the FireFox browser console, respectively.
[image: CORS and mixed content errors]

Comment: _The above code was working fine a month ago,_ i guess you missed this one.

Comment: POST XHR http://127.0.0.1:5000/send [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 13ms]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/send. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>

Comment: This is what i get in console!!

Comment: So then the problem is in fact a CORS issue. What's in the address bar when you're viewing the page making the request? If it's anything other than something like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/somepage.html`, then that's probably the cause.

Comment: Yes, .fail() callback fun. is invoked!!

Comment: Ohh, man You are really life savior, i was doing exactly the same mistake, as you discussed, I was actually trying to run the html file directly in browser and, and expecting the output from AJAX to return, without awaring of the CORS issue.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad this was helpful. :)